# Angular 2 submits form even with errors

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-formbuilder

I'm trying to implement a Angular 2 Form with Form Builder.
This is my component.html

```
 <div class="login-container">
  <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="login(loginForm.$value)" #f="ngForm" novalidate class="col-md-5">
    <div class="text-center">
      <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <input id="username" formControlName="username" type="text" placeholder="Usuario" aria-describedby="Usuario" class="form-control">
    <input id="password" formControlName="password" type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" aria-describedby="Contraseña" class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">Entrar</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

And this is my component.ts

```
...
constructor(
    private router: Router, 
    private authenticationService: AuthService,
    public fb: FormBuilder) { 
      this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
        username: ['', Validators.required],
        password: ['', Validators.required]
      });    
    }
...
login(value:any) {
    this.loading = true;
// Here goes the authentication logic.
      }
```

But my form always submits even if it has errors, or the inputs are blank. Am I doing anything wrong? Or Does it lack of something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, that is the expected behavior the way it is coded. If you don't want the form to submit when there are errors you need to disable your submit button when it is in the invalid state.

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">Entrar</button>
```

Comment: I thought it could be done without disabling the button. I also tried relying validation to the browser by itself, so I removed novalidate attribute to the form, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Why would you not want to disable the button? It is an unusual  use case to want to allow users to submit invalid form data. Also it reduces performance running logic every time an invalid form is submitted when you can avoid all that by disabling the action to begin with.

Comment: As far as HTML is concerned if there is an enabled 'Submit' button, it will submit the associated form data each time it is clicked regardless of form state. Aside from disabling the button, you cannot prevent that natively.

Answer (score 1):

You could send the valid property from the form.

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="login(loginForm.$value, f.valid)" novalidate>
```

And then check it inside the submit function.

```
login(value:any, valid: boolean) {
    if (!valid) {
      return;
    }

    this.loading = true;
     // Here goes the authentication logic.
 }
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid reaching the login function. I also tried without novalidate attribute in the form, waiting for the browser attempt to validate the form and not letting it submit, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Personally I don't see why you would avoid checking this in the function. I think it is good for readability and makes testing easier. You could also send the whole form object and display messages based on the validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the button available but check the form on submit then you can do the following by using '**updateOn: submit**', this is new since Angular5: https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-5-forms-update-9587c3735cd3

Or, another option as found here (look for kara's post): https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14527 :

```
  <form [formGroup]="heroForm" #formDir="ngForm">
  <div *ngIf="heroForm.hasError('required', 'name') && formDir.submitted">
     Name is required.
  </div>
   <input formControlName="name">
   <input formControlName="power">
   <button [disabled]="heroForm.invalid && formDir.submitted">
      Submit 
   </button>
</form>
```